# Change size of terminal_panel = node_barplot in ctree

Tags: plot, nodes, font-size, ctree, cptbarplot

I need to change the size of the terminal panels of the nodes that are as barplot in a ctree, because I can't see the 13 species (response variable) and also the size of the letter is very small in the whole tree. I have tried several ways but I have not been able to do it.

> dataasfactor=CART_monitoring_no_loc_month_less_spp
> dataasfactor <- as.data.frame(unclass(dataasfactor),
> stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
> str(dataasfactor)

> arbol1=ctree(Species~.,dataasfactor)
> plot(arbol1, gp = gpar(fontsize = 12))
> print(arbol1)

> plot(arbol1)

> png(file = "conditionalClassification2.png", res=80, width = 2000, height = 800)

> pdf(file = "conditionalClassification2.pdf", width = 100, height = 50)
> plot(arbol1)
> dev.off()